# Cron job Linux Shell command SiteGround - What Directory does it run in?

Tags: linux, cron

New to Siteground hosting, Cron jobs and Linux.

I have a directory where I want to remove files older than 30 days on my WordPress website.

The Linux shell command is

```
find path/to/files/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

The question is about the path to use. I don't know where this Cron job is running from.

If I create a cron job with just

```
find *
```

The log file produces the following results...

```
tmp
tmp/somefile1
tmp/somefile2
etc...
```

Where is tmp? And what should I use in my **path** for my command to get to where I want it.

If I FTP to my site using FileZilla, this is the path to my directory in question...

```
/mydomain.com/public_html/sr
```

So, if I edit my Cron job to execute the following command...

```
find /mydomain.com/public_html/sr/*
```

I get

```
find: '/mydomain.com/public_html/sr/*': No such file or directory
```

So, just not sure how to specify the path for my Cron job so that it operates on the desired directory.

Comment: Questions about specific web hosting services are probably more appropriate for [su].

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after much searching.

```
/home/customer/www/yourdomain.com/public_html/sr
```

Hope this helps others. The support was no help at all.

Comment: That seems specific to a particular hosting service, it's not true for `cron` in general.